# Set default value attributes form PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, forms

I'm trying to change an field to a default string everytime an polygon is created in attributes form.

For now I have seen Alexandro [code](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/09/30/configure-editing-form-widgets-using-pyqgis/) and based on that I have something like this:

```
layername = "ZAPM"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
field = "ID_PM"
list_values = {"ID_PM001":"ID_PM001"}

def field_to_value_map(layer, field, list_values):
    config = {'map' : list_values}
    widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('ValueMap',config)
    field_idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
    layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(field_idx, widget_setup)

field_to_value_map(layer, field, list_values)
```

[image]

This code is great, but it's half completed, I want the form field to be a string, not dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did find was to get the [**editorWidgetSetup** **type and config**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346363/how-to-set-widget-type-to-attachment#:%7E:text=More%20generic%20answer%20(recommendation))

After some search, and using this script to find both type and config, this is my simple final code:

```
layername = "layer_name"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
field = "field_name"


def zapm(layer, field):
    config =  {'IsMultiline': False, 'UseHtml': False}

    layer.editFormConfig().setWidgetConfig("TextEdit", config)
    default_value = QgsDefaultValue()
    default_value.setExpression("'Your value'") // Keep the ''  inside of ""
    field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
    
    # Set the default value for the specific field
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(field_index, default_value)
  

zapm(layer, field)
```